# Post a URL parameter to an input text box triggering the display autocomplete suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that contains a user input workflow as follows: A user enters text, like a zip code, into an input box on one page, the value is passed to a URL parameter called "search", the URL parameter value is posted to an input box on another page, and autocomplete results are displayed. My problem is when the URL value is posted to the destination input box, the autocomplete suggestions won't display unless a user interacts with, and begins typing in the input the box.

So far, I have tried appending a "space" after the page has loaded to get the autocomplete suggestions to display. I have also tried keyup, keydown, and keypress, but I am beginning to wonder if I am using them properly. I apologize for being a jQuery novice, but any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Zip code or state"> 

<script>
//Get URL variables that come from search boxes of other pages
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("?search=") > -1) {
    function getUrlVars(){
      var vars = [], hash;
      var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('/');
      for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
          hash = hashes[i].split('=');
          vars.push(hash[0]);
          vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
      }
      return vars;
    }
//Read URL variables and post to "search-input" input text box
$(document).ready(function() {
      var otherPageSearch = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()['search']);
      $('#search-input').val(otherPageSearch);
      $('#search-input').focus();
    //Append a Space to try to get Autocomplete options to display
      $(window).on('load', function() { 
        $('#search-input').val(function() {
          return this.value + ' ';
        });
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

When the URL variable is read and passed to the input box, I am expecting the autocomplete to display a list of results without any user interaction within the input box (clicking, typing, etc).

Comment: Note that `.load()` is deprecated as event listener method....see docs.

Comment: Edited/updated. Thanks for pointing that out @charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

One of the quick fix for this could be Add a keydown event in your when you are setting focus on textbox.

```
$('#search-input').on('focus',function(){$(this).keydown();})
```

There could be other solutions as well. But this should work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an event listener for the input box 'onchange'